# Organizing documents across libraries using tags

Tags: search, content, libraries, tags

Our new SP-intranet will display content based on what department creates it but I also would like to display the content on another subsite based on categories (forms, guides, templates etc.). My idea was to do this by using tags to label the content and use a Content Search Web Part to retrieve the content to the category site.

My problem is however that when I use the "Restrict by tag" function, the search comes up emptyhanded... But my documents should be properly tagged.

Any ideas on what I might have done wrong? Or thoughts on how to create a solution to display content based on categories some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column (Categories) and a new view which displays the new category. Use one view for your intranet root site and another for your subsite (turn off the new category from the view in the root site).